# Удаление и добавление элемента массива

Tags: c++

Как в статическом массиве удалить элемент, индекс которого кратен 3 и добавить элемент после отрицательного элемента? 3 день не получается реализовать это

```
#include "pch.h"
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    const int SIZE = 10;
    double arr[SIZE], newArr[SIZE-4];

    for (int i = 0; i < SIZE; i++) {
        cout << "arr [" << i << "] = ";
        cin >> arr[i];
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < SIZE; ++i) {


        if (i % 3 !=0) {
            newArr[i] = arr[i];

        if (arr[i] < 0) {
            arr[i + i] = 10;
        }
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < SIZE; i++) {
        cout << newArr[i]<<"\n";
    }

}
```

Comment: Покажите код ваших попыток и объясните, что именно значит "не получается".

Comment: Отредактировал.

Comment: У вас первый и второй массив ведёт `i`, а должны "вести" разные переменные. Для одной - не будет толку. Второй например будет `j`. Тогда если i - увеличилось, а j нет, то произойдёт удаление. А если i увеличится на 1 а j на два - то добавится новый елемент.

Comment: Вам придется делать два прохода по исходному массиву и динамически распределять память под `newArr`.